# NIC down after wakeonlan

Tags: networking, wpa-supplicant, wakeonlan, nic

I've setup wakeonlan on an Ubuntu 22.04 machine using `iw`, following [this tutorial](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/configure-wireless-wake-on-lan-for-linux-wifi-wowlan-card/):

```
$ sudo iw phy0 wowlan enable magic-packet disconnect
```

I then control the machine over ssh with `wakeonlan <MAC>` and `systemctl suspend`, this most often works. But sometimes, after `wakeonlan`, the network interface is down and does not appear in `ifconfig` output anymore (unless `-a` is provided). Trying to re-enable it causes an error:

```
$ sudo ifconfig wlp4s0 up
SIOCSIFFLAGS Input/output error
```

The network manager service provides the following logs:

```
Feb 27 21:45:26 Z390-GAMING-X NetworkManager[33337]: <warn>  [1677530726.0879] device (wlp4s0): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#1).
Feb 27 21:45:26 Z390-GAMING-X NetworkManager[33337]: <error> [1677530726.5096] device (wlp4s0): Couldn't initialize supplicant interface: GDBus.Error:fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.UnknownError: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
```

with the following logs for `wpa_supplicant`:

```
Feb 27 21:45:26 Z390-GAMING-X wpa_supplicant[835]: Could not set interface wlp4s0 flags (UP): Input/output error
Feb 27 21:45:26 Z390-GAMING-X wpa_supplicant[835]: nl80211: Could not set interface 'wlp4s0' UP
Feb 27 21:45:26 Z390-GAMING-X wpa_supplicant[835]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp4s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
```

---

I've tried to follow [this](https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=151625) (unmask wpa_supplicant.service) and disabling WiFi Powersave, without success. Any ideas on how to solve this are welcome. My network card is an Intel Wireless-AC 9260.

---

A perhaps important note: I could not setup wakeonlan with `ethtool` as described in Ubuntu's [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan), since I got the following output:

```
$ sudo ethtool wlp4s0
Settings for wlp4s0:
    Link detected: yes
```

That is, there is no `Wake-on:` field as I would expect. Trying to enable it with `ethtool` returns an error:

```
$ sudo ethtool -s wlp4s0 wol g
netlink error: Operation not supported
```

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages **you** got on **your system**. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: Here's my guess: You have a connection, periodically re-authorized by `wpasupplicant`. When you `systemctl suspend`, `wpasupplicant` misses many of these re-auths. When the system starts via wake-on-lan, `wpasupplicant` is complaining that it can't. `service NetworkManager status` might help.